# Changing image sequence in compositor with multilayer (EXR) files using python does not show any layers

Tags: python, compositing-nodes

I have a compositor setup where I have an image sequence made of EXR files.
I then use the separate layers and connect them to some other nodes later.

Now I want to use a python script to use different images.
With my current code it somehow removes/collapses the layers from the node.
Is there some variable I need to change so that it properly registers the imported images as multilayer files?

```
def get_image_files(image_folder_path, image_extension=".exr"):
    image_files = list()
    for file_name in os.listdir(image_folder_path):
        if file_name.endswith(image_extension):
            image_files.append(file_name)
    image_files.sort()

    print(image_files)

    return image_files


def add_compositor_nodes(image_sequence, duration):

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    compositor_node_tree = scene.node_tree
    image_node = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['base_layers_image']
    image_node.image = image_sequence
    image_node.frame_duration = duration
    image_node.frame_start = 1
    image_node.frame_offset = 0



def import_image_sequence_into_compositor(image_folder_path, fps):
    image_files = get_image_files(image_folder_path)

    file_info = list()
    for image_name in image_files:
        file_info.append({"name": image_name})

    bpy.ops.image.open(directory=image_folder_path, files=file_info)

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    scene.use_nodes = True


    image_data_name = image_files[0]
    image_sequence = bpy.data.images[image_data_name]
    duration = len(image_files)
    add_compositor_nodes(image_sequence, duration)

    
    
image_folder_path = image_folder_import_path
import_image_sequence_into_compositor(image_folder_path, fps)
```